# Dispatch vs Return in react-redux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I start learn redux-react .Please help me difference between Dispatch and Return in redux-react?Can they replace each other?.

Comment: What do you mean by `Return`? `dispatch()` is a method in the Redux store used to dispatch an action and eventually trigger a state update.

Answer (score 4):

I think you have misunderstood the concept og the dispatch method. 
Take some time and read the Redux documentation, here specifically for Actions, which is where the dispatch method is being used:
http://redux.js.org/docs/basics/Actions.html

Here is an illustration of where the dispatch comes to play.

[image: Illustration of dispatch method]

Comment: Funny. I'm reading a blog about useEffect that uses dispatches as last commands where I was expecting a return. Therefore I cam here to verify that dispatch is not a replacement for return though I genuinely know what dispatch means.